# Disable when the mouse is at the edge of the screen in windows 7, shows desktop.

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

When I move the mouse to the edge of the screen in windows 7, the view changes to the desktop.

How do I disable this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click on this rectangle and deselect the option "Preview desktop".

Comment: Which rectangle? Found it! Thanks.

Comment: The one at the lower-right corner of the screen, that is, the one that the mouse is hovering above when the desktop is shown.

Comment: Mine says "Peek at desktop".  Whatever, it appears to have fixed it.